# How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit

How can I tell what mode the shell is in, from within the shell?

I've tried looking at the [platform](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) module, but it seems only to tell you about "the bit architecture and the linkage format used for the executable". My binary is compiled as 64bit (I'm running on OS X 10.6), so it seems to always report 64bit even though I'm using the methods [described here](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/python.1.html) to force 32bit mode.

Comment: I'm having problems building and loading some modules on OS X 10.6.  Specifically pysco, which is complaining I'm running in 64bit mode.  This is under a virtualenv as well so there is some extra complications I need to work through...

Comment: I'd like to know because when I use something like PyInstaller to create a stand-alone binary distributable (to give to users who might not have (the right version of) Python installed, the binary I produce will be 32/64 bit depending on the Python I run PyInstaller with. Ideally I'm thinking I'd like to automatically name the resulting binary/archive file with '32' or '64' in the filename, rather than having to manually rename the files depending on where I execute the 'make' command from.

Answer (score 501, accepted):

One way is to look at `sys.maxsize` as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#cross-platform):

```
$ python-32 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
('7fffffff', False)
$ python-64 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
('7fffffffffffffff', True)
```

On Windows, run the same commands formatted as follows:

```
python -c "import sys;print(\"%x\" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)"
```

`sys.maxsize` was introduced in Python 2.6.  If you need a test for older systems, this slightly more complicated test should work on all Python 2 and 3 releases:

```
$ python-32 -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'
32
$ python-64 -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'
64
```

BTW, you might be tempted to use `platform.architecture()` for this.  Unfortunately, its results are not always reliable, [particularly in the case of OS X universal binaries](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.architecture).

```
$ arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6 -c 'import sys,platform; print platform.architecture()[0], sys.maxsize > 2**32'
64bit True
$ arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.6 -c 'import sys,platform; print platform.architecture()[0], sys.maxsize > 2**32'
64bit False
```

Comment: Using sys.maxint will not work to detect a 64-bit Python when running Windows (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411079/why-does-the-python-2-7-amd-64-installer-seem-to-run-python-in-32-bit-mode)).  Instead, use struct.calcsize("P") for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I've substantially revised the answer to show the now documented `sys.maxsize` test for Python 2.6+ and the `struct` test used by the `platform` module which also works for older versions of Python 2.

Comment: This doesn't work in IronPython, sys.maxsize is 2**31 for both 32 bit and 64 bit IronPython

Comment: Note: sys.maxsize / sys.maxint / strcut.calcsize('P') doesn't help when you run a Python interpreter of 32 bits on 64 bits machine and need to know **the architecture of the machine**. For this platform.machine() is useful - at least for Linux & Windows.

Comment: Yinon, that's true but that's not what the question asked for.  And, on those CPUs where it is possible to run, say, either 32-bit or 64-bit binaries, the arch of the machine is usually not all that relevant to a Python program; what matters is what arch the Python interpreter itself is running as.

Comment: sys.version will also include architecture information of the python binary

Comment: @Efren, no, `sys.version` is not sufficient.  It shows the compiler used to build Python but generally does not show the running architecture. For example, with OS X universal fat binaries, sys.version is identical for all architectures (32-bit, 64-bit) in the same file.

Comment: Well, it does show it in windows
> python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
> py -3.4
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32

Comment: On windows cmd, you need to put the double quotes on the outside and the single quotes on the inside or else it will produce a syntax error. That's probably because windows thinks spaces between single-quotes are still argument delimiters. It may be helpful to adjust this answer to accommodate that fact.

Comment: How distinguish between amd64 and ia64 on Windows?

Comment: I used `python -c "import sys;print('%x' % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)"` which works on both Linux and Windows (which requires double quotes for the param)

Answer (score 301):

When starting the Python interpreter in the terminal/command line you may also see a line like:

`Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Where `[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]` means 64-bit Python.
Works for my particular setup.

Comment: so this is what? 64bit python or 32bit python?

Comment: @phpJs 64 bit because of `[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: Unfortunately only works for Windows versions of Python. My OSX installation returns `Python 2.7.8 (v2.7.8:ee879c0ffa11, Jun 29, 2014, 21:07:35)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple In. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin`

Comment: On cygwin, you get this answer: `Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 25 2014, 14:04:36) [GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin`

Comment: Answered my question (Windows) which was I'm going to see that I'm on x64 hardware anyway. since I know that its 64-bit, the question I believe the OP had was is the interpreter the 32 or 64-bit console?

Comment: This info can be found out in code by calling `sys.version`. I get for example `('3.4.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:54:04) [MSC ' 'v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]')` or `2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]`

Comment: @otterb wouldnt that return the system version and not necessarily the  version of python that is installed and running. You could have windows 64  bit but may have installed the 32 bit python

Comment: The one-liner is `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"`

Answer (score 232):

Basically a variant on Matthew Marshall's answer (with struct from the std.library):

```
import struct
print struct.calcsize("P") * 8
```

Comment: Imho, better than ctypes version - works even with older Python.

Comment: Very useful, can be used in one line. 
$ python -c 'import struct; print struct.calcsize("P") * 8'

Comment: print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8) is better.

Comment: so copy-paste oneliner for Python3: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P')*8)"`

Answer (score 103):

Try using ctypes to get the size of a void pointer:

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)
```

It'll be 4 for 32 bit or 8 for 64 bit.

Comment: That works, too, although it does have the possible slight disadvantage of an unnecessary import and module load if you don't otherwise need ctypes: the sys module, otoh, is compiled into the interpreter.

Comment: please help me understand: on my 64b installation `python -c 'import ctypes; print ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)'` returns **8**. Or should it be `python -c 'import ctypes; print ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp) * 8'` ?

Comment: The function returns the size in [bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) (4 or 8). If you need the size in [bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) (32 or 64) you have to multiply with 8. b_is_python_64bit = (ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp) == 8)

Comment: Just call `python -c "import ctypes; print(32 if ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)==4 else 64, 'bit CPU')"`

Answer (score 90):

To paraphrase the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405971 —

**Open python console:**

```
import platform
platform.architecture()[0]
```

it should display the '64bit' or '32bit' according to your platform.

**Alternatively**( [in case of OS X binaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#cross-platform) ):

```
import sys
sys.maxsize > 2**32 
# it should display True in case of 64bit and False in case of 32bit
```

Comment: patform module is not always reliable see docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html this is true also for some Windows application

Answer (score 35):

On my Centos Linux system I did the following:

1) Started the Python interpreter (I'm using 2.6.6)
2) Ran the following code:

```
import platform
print(platform.architecture())
```

and it gave me

```
(64bit, 'ELF')
```

Answer (score 20):

Grouping everything...

Considering that:

- The question is asked for *OSX* (I have an old (and cracked) *VM* with an ancient *Python* version)
- My "main" *env* is *Win*
- I only have the *032bit* (*Python*) version installed on *Win* (and I built a "crippled" one on *Linux* (*Ubuntu*))

I'm going to exemplify on all 3 platforms, using *Python 3* and *Python 2*.

##### 1. Check [[Python.Docs]: sys.maxsize](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize)

Compare value to ***0x100000000*** (*4294967296* or ***2 ** 32***):

- Greater for *064bit* (***pc064***)
- Smaller for *032bit* (***pc032***)

Example:

- *OSX 9 pc064*:

  - *Python 2.7.10 pc064*:

    > ```py
    > >>> import sys
    > >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
    > 'Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 05:51:29) \n[GCC 4.8.2] on darwin'
    > >>> hex(sys.maxsize), sys.maxsize > 0x100000000
    > ('0x7fffffffffffffff', True)
    > ```
- *Ubuntu 16 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.2 pc064*:

    > ```py
    > >>> import sys
    > >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
    > 'Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux'
    > >>> hex(sys.maxsize), sys.maxsize > 0x100000000
    > ('0x7fffffffffffffff', True)
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.4 pc032*:

    > ```py
    > >>> import sys
    > >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
    > 'Python 3.6.4 (default, Apr 25 2018, 23:55:56) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux'
    > >>> hex(sys.maxsize), sys.maxsize > 0x100000000
    > ('0x7fffffff', False)
    > ```
- *Win 10 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.4 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import sys
    > >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
    > 'Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32'
    > >>> hex(sys.maxsize), sys.maxsize > 0x100000000
    > ('0x7fffffffffffffff', True)
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.2 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import sys
    > >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
    > 'Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32'
    > >>> hex(sys.maxsize), sys.maxsize > 0x100000000
    > ('0x7fffffff', False)
    > ```

##### 2. Use [[Python.Docs]: struct.calcsize(format)](https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.calcsize)

Determine the object size produced by the (pointer) format. In other words, determines the pointer size (`sizeof(void*)`).

Example:

- *OSX 9 pc064*:

  - *Python 2.7.10 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import struct
    > >>> struct.calcsize("P") * 8
    > 64
    > ```
- *Ubuntu 16 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.2 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import struct
    > >>> struct.calcsize("P") * 8
    > 64
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.4 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import struct
    > >>> struct.calcsize("P") * 8
    > 32
    > ```
- *Win 10 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.4 pc064*:

    > ```py
    > >>> import struct
    > >>> struct.calcsize("P") * 8
    > 64
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.2 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import struct
    > >>> struct.calcsize("P") * 8
    > 32
    > ```

##### 3. Use [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)

It also boils down to determining the size of a pointer (`sizeof(void*)`).

*CTypes* side notes:

- Might use ***#2.*** in certain situations (via [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (main) cpython/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py))
- Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for common mistakes when using it (in more complex scenarios (*e.g.* calling functions))
- [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546) might also be interesting

Example:

- *OSX 9 pc064*:

  - *Python 2.7.10 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import ctypes
    > >>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) * 8
    > 64
    > ```
- *Ubuntu 16 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.2 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import ctypes
    > >>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) * 8
    > 64
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.4 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import ctypes
    > >>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) * 8
    > 32
    > ```
- *Win 10 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.4 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import ctypes
    > >>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) * 8
    > 64
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.2 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import ctypes
    > >>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) * 8
    > 32
    > ```

##### 4. Check [[Python.Docs]: platform.architecture(executable=sys.executable, bits='', linkage='')](https://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.architecture)

**!!! NOT reliable on *OSX* !!!** due to multi arch executable (or *.dylib*) format (in some cases, uses ***#2.***).

Example:

- *OSX 9 pc064*:

  - *Python 2.7.10 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import platform
    > >>> platform.architecture()
    > ('64bit', '')
    > ```
- *Ubuntu 16 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.2 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import platform
    > >>> platform.architecture()
    > ('64bit', 'ELF')
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.4 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import platform
    > >>> platform.architecture()
    > ('32bit', 'ELF')
    > ```
- *Win 10 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.4 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import platform
    > >>> platform.architecture()
    > ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.2 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import platform
    > >>> platform.architecture()
    > ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
    > ```

##### 5. Invoke an external command

- [[Man7]: FILE(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) via [[Python.Docs]: os.system(command)](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)
- Lame workaround (*gainarie*)
- Limitations of ***#4.*** apply (sometimes it might not even work):

Example:

- *OSX 9 pc064*:

  - *Python 2.7.10 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import os
    > >>> os.system("file {:s}".format(os.path.realpath(sys.executable)))
    > /opt/OPSWbuildtools/2.0.6/bin/python2.7.global: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
    > ```
- *Ubuntu 16 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.2 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import os
    > >>> os.system("file {:s}".format(os.path.realpath(sys.executable)))
    > /usr/bin/python3.5: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=59a8ef36ca241df24686952480966d7bc0d7c6ea, stripped
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.4 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import os
    > >>> os.system("file {:s}".format(os.path.realpath(sys.executable)))
    > /home/cfati/Work/Dev/Python-3.6.4/python: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=5c3d4eeadbd13cd91445d08f90722767b0747de2, not stripped
    > ```
- *Win 10 pc064*:

  - *file* utility is not present, there are other 3<sup>rd</sup>-party tools (*Nix* emulators: *MSYS2*, *Cygwin*, ...) that can be used, but I'm not going to insist on them

##### 6. Check *env* *var*s

- Via [[Python.Docs]: os.environ](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ):
- *Win* specific:

  - *%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%* (or others)

Example:

- *Win 10 pc064*:

  - *Python 3.5.4 pc064*:

    > ```
    > >>> import os
    > >>> os.environ["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"]
    > 'AMD64'
    > ```
  - *Python 3.6.2 pc032*:

    > ```
    > >>> import os
    > >>> os.environ["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"]
    > 'x86'
    > ```

##### 7. Check [[Python.Docs]: sys.version](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version)

- Also **displayed in the 1<sup>st</sup> line** when starting the interpreter

  - On some platforms, it might contain (textual) architecture information:

    [image: Img0]
- Check ***#1.***

Answer (score 17):

For a non-programmatic solution, look in the Activity Monitor. It lists the architecture of 64-bit processes as “Intel (64-bit)”.

Comment: A very nice alternative answer for those of us using Mac OS 10.x.x
Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

On **Windows 10**

Open the cmd termial and start python interpreter by typing >python as shown in the below image

[image: Img]

If the interpreter info at start contains **AMD64**, it's 64-bit, otherwise, 32-bit bit.

Comment: Many common distributions of the python binary don't print this verbose statement at startup

Answer (score 11):

[`platform.architecture()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.architecture) notes say:

> Note:
>   On Mac OS X (and perhaps other platforms), executable files may be universal files containing multiple architectures.
>
> To get at the “64-bitness” of the current interpreter, it is more reliable
>   to query the sys.maxsize attribute:

```
import sys
is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32
```

Answer (score 11):

Do a `python -VV` in the command line. It should return the version.

Comment: This does not seem to provide the info needed to answer the question

Comment: `Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]` Thanks

Comment: it is not providing in my case too: `python3.6 -VV: 
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
[GCC 8.4.0]`

Comment: I got `Python 2.7.16` only

Answer (score 10):

Based on [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405971/),

```
import sys
n_bits = 32 << bool(sys.maxsize >> 32)
```

n_bits will have 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: Such a beautiful and elegant line of code!  Needs some commenting though, so here you go: If shifting the sys.maxsize by 32-Bits to the Right stills leaves you with a non-zero value; then the Architecture is greater than 32-Bits.  Use bool() to return either a 0 or 1.  Note: If your shifted value is >0 then bool will simply return 1.  Use that 0/1 number to shift the 32 over to the Left to return either itself (32) or 64.

Answer (score 8):

`struct.calcsize("P")` returns size of the bytes required to store a single pointer. On a 32-bit system, it would return 4 bytes. On a 64-bit system, it would return 8 bytes.

So the following would return `32` if you're running 32-bit python and `64` if you're running 64-bit python:

**Python 2**

```
import struct;print struct.calcsize("P") * 8
```

**Python 3**

```
import struct;print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
C:\Users\xyz>python

Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov XY ..., 19:24:24) **[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32**
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

after hitting python in cmd

Comment: So with version is it? 64 or 32?

Answer (score 4):

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 **64 bit (AMD64)**]

Comment: Doesn't apply to *OSX*.

Answer (score 0):

Platform Architecture is not the reliable way.
Instead us:

```
$ arch -i386 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform, sys
>>> platform.architecture(), sys.maxsize
(('64bit', ''), 2147483647)
>>> ^D
$ arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform, sys
>>> platform.architecture(), sys.maxsize
(('64bit', ''), 9223372036854775807)
```

Answer (score 0):

`platform.architecture()` is problematic (and expensive).

Conveniently test for `sys.maxsize > 2**32` since Py2.6 .

This is a reliable test for the actual (default) pointer size and compatible at least since Py2.3: `struct.calcsize('P') == 8`. Also: `ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p) == 8`.

Notes: There can be builds with gcc option `-mx32` or so, which are 64bit architecture applications, but use 32bit pointers as default (saving memory and speed). 'sys.maxsize = ssize_t' may not strictly represent the C pointer size (its usually `2**31 - 1` anyway). And there were/are systems which have different pointer sizes for code and data and it needs to be clarified what exactly is the purpose of discerning "32bit or 64bit mode?"