# How and why is the dictionary hashes different in python2 and python3?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, hash, cpython

As an experiment, the hashes in `python2` and `python3` seem to be different:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python -c "from collections import Counter; x = Counter({'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'foobar': 1, 'barfoo': 1}); print(x.most_common())"
[('foobar', 1), ('foo', 1), ('bar', 1), ('barfoo', 1)]
alvas@ubi:~$ python -c "from collections import Counter; x = Counter({'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'foobar': 1, 'barfoo': 1}); print(x.most_common())"
[('foobar', 1), ('foo', 1), ('bar', 1), ('barfoo', 1)]
alvas@ubi:~$ python -c "from collections import Counter; x = Counter({'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'foobar': 1, 'barfoo': 1}); print(x.most_common())"
[('foobar', 1), ('foo', 1), ('bar', 1), ('barfoo', 1)]


alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "from collections import Counter; x = Counter({'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'foobar': 1, 'barfoo': 1}); print(x.most_common())"
[('barfoo', 1), ('foobar', 1), ('bar', 1), ('foo', 1)]
alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "from collections import Counter; x = Counter({'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'foobar': 1, 'barfoo': 1}); print(x.most_common())"
[('foo', 1), ('barfoo', 1), ('bar', 1), ('foobar', 1)]
alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "from collections import Counter; x = Counter({'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'foobar': 1, 'barfoo': 1}); print(x.most_common())"
[('bar', 1), ('barfoo', 1), ('foobar', 1), ('foo', 1)]
```

And when we look at string hashes, `python3` hashes seems to be dynamic:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python -c "print 'abc'.__hash__()"
1453079729188098211
alvas@ubi:~$ python -c "print 'abc'.__hash__()"
1453079729188098211
alvas@ubi:~$ python -c "print 'abc'.__hash__()"
1453079729188098211


alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "print ('abc'.__hash__())"
-4165906745021293940
alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "print ('abc'.__hash__())"
-4676677077013862663
alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "print ('abc'.__hash__())"
5261896652811750722
```

My question is **why and how is the hash different?**

**Which hashing algorithm is each one of them using? Where are I find the exact CPython code where the string hashing happens?**

**Is there a way to unrandomize the hashes?**

---

## EDITED

After reading the [PEP398](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html) , this can unset the random hash but it's not recommended due to security issues.

```
alvas@ubi:~$ export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "print ('abc'.__hash__())"
4596069200710135518
alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "print ('abc'.__hash__())"
4596069200710135518
alvas@ubi:~$ python3 -c "print ('abc'.__hash__())"
4596069200710135518
```

Comment: Hash randomisation - related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956313/dictionary-ordering-non-deterministic-in-python3

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558709/the-similar-method-from-the-nltk-module-produces-different-results-on-different

Comment: Is there a way to unrandomize hashes? `python3 -c "import random; random.seed(0); print ('abc'.__hash__())"` don't work =(

Comment: @alvas: read the PEP, there is an [environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED). The source is all in https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/pyhash.c

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters!!! That explains a lot =)

Comment: If you need consistent results, you're probably best off not using the default `__hash__` methods at all. They're not going to be consistent across 32-bit and 64-bit builds of CPython, or across different Python implementations, and they could easily change across CPython releases.