# Detect platform architecture independent from Python executable

Tags: python, cpu-architecture, platform

There are all sorts of ways to determine whether the Python executable is a 32 or 64 Bit program. But is there a way to determine if the machine supports x64? All I found results in 32 Bit for a x86 Python distribution on a 64 Bit machine.

One way is to use `sys.maxsize > (1 << 32)`, but it comes with the problem mentioned above.

Edit: Himal's first link already provides a somewhat-solution for Windows, checking the `PROGRAMFILES` environment variable. I could then see if it contains the string `(x86`)`.

A cross-platform solution would be nice, though. `platform.platform()` is **not** a solution, I tried this *before I asked the question already*. It returns 32-Bit on 64-Bit Windows when using a 32-Bit Python executable.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2208869/1189040) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1842575/1189040)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect 64bit OS (windows) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208828/detect-64bit-os-windows-in-python)

Comment: @Himal Your first link provides a solution for my problem on Windows, but I need something more cross-platform, and should work for at least Linux and Darwin as well.

Comment: @RobertoAllende Same link as the Himal's second, and no, this is not a solution to the problem. As I pointed out specifically in the question, I want to detect a 64-Bit OS even if a 32-Bit Python executable is running. `platform.platform()` does this **not**.