# open large gzip file (~1gb) in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner in python and trying to learn python. I have written few line of code to open a large gzip file (size of ~ 1gb) and want to extract some content, however I am getting memory related error. could somebody please guide me how open the gzip with limited memory. I have put a part of code that is throwing error.

```
import os
import gzip

with gzip.open("test.gz","rb") as peak:
     for line in peak:
         file_content = line.read().decode("utf-8")             
         print(file_content)
```

> Error: File "/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 276, in read
>   return self._buffer.read(size)

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for quick reply. I have updated my post

Comment: Sure you're not hitting the memory limit? Consider reading the file in chunks. You can iterate over the fileObject returned from `gzip.open`.

Comment: Thanks @EliranAbdoo for reply !
I tried to iterate over the object but its throwing another error

` file_content = line.read()

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
`

Comment: @GyanPrakashMishra it's because the line is the context itself. As the interpreter says, it's a bytes object (so just remove the `read()` and decode it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to recreate your issue but I am unable to. Using `fallocate` I create a big file, then gzip it, but hit no error in Python

```
$ fallocate -l 2G tempfile.img
$ gzip tempfile.img
$ ipython
>>> import gzip
>>> with gzip.open('tempfile.img.gz', 'rb') as fIn:
>>>    content = fIn.read()
```

If you hit an exception, it should have some name like `OSError` or something more specific. My guess is that you have a 32-bit installation of Python which would impose memory limits in the gigabyte range. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842544/how-do-i-detect-if-python-is-running-as-a-64-bit-application#1842575) SO thread covers a way to check if you're running 32- or 64-bit.

If you post the name of the exception or a reproducible example, then I can update this answer.

Comment: Here is architecture of system and installed 64-bit only 

`>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', '')
>>> 
`
ok I will try to reproduce the example