# Finding the architectures that Python was built for, but from within Python itself

Tags: python, macos, architecture

Essentially I am looking for a way to find the following, but from within Python without having to run system commands:

```
$ file `which python2.7`
/Library/.../2.7/bin/python2.7: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/.../2.7/bin/python2.7 (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/Library/.../2.7/bin/python2.7 (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Something like:

```
>>> get_mac_python_archs()
['i386', 'x86_64']
>>>
```

Possible?

Comment: What's wrong with using system commands like file or otool? Before asking someone to figure out how to do this, it would be polite to explain why you can't do it the easy way, if only to convince us that you really can't do it the easy way.

Comment: @user57368: all the better if this information is built into Python lib, otherwise I'll have to launch a new process (`lipo` or `file`) that would add to the startup time of my program ... though that doesn't seem to be a significant delay.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no truly reliable way other than to examine the executable files themselves to see which architectures have been `lipo`-ed together, in other words, what `file` does. While the `distutils.util.get_platform()` noted elsewhere probably comes the closest, it is based on configuration information at Python build time and the criteria used has changed between releases and even among distributions of the same release.

For example, if you built a Python 2.6 on OS X 10.6 with the 4-way universal option (`ppc`, `ppc64`, `i386`, `x86_64`), `get_platform()` should report `macosx-10.6-universal`.  However, the Apple-suppled Python 2.6 in OS X 10.6 reports the same string even though it is only a 3-way build (no `ppc64`).  EDIT: That may not be the best example since, come to think of it, you probably couldn't build a `ppc64` variant with the 10.6 SDK.  However, the point still holds that the platform string is too context dependent to be totally reliable.  It may be reliable enough for *some* needs, though.  Otherwise, calling out to `file` or `otool` etc is likely the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The function `platform.architecture` returns just the platform working:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79359, Mar 24 2010, 01:32:55) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.machine()
'i386'
```

the nearest I can get to is by using [`distutils.util.get_platform`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.get_platform):

```
>>> import distutils.util
>>> distutils.util.get_platform()
'macosx-10.3-fat'
```

which is the full answer if you are using Python 2.7/3.2, as you can see in the documentation. "Starting from Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 the architecture fat3 is used for a 3-way universal build (ppc, i386, x86_64) and intel is used for a univeral build with the i386 and x86_64 architectures"