# How to install python 2.7.5 as 64bit?

Tags: python, macos

When downloading the python 2.7.5 [here](http://www.python.org/getit/), I download the python installer with the link "Python 2.7.5 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer (for Mac OS X 10.6 and later [2])".
Installed the python, I cd the directory "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7" and execute the following python code:

```
 import sys
 print sys.maxint
```

and I get 2147483647 which means I am runing the python of 32bit version. How can I install the python of 64bit version?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you running?  What is your CPU?

Comment: This might give you some clues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411079/why-does-the-python-2-7-amd-64-installer-seem-to-run-python-in-32-bit-mode

Comment: @Paul OS: Darwin localhost 12.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: Well, I'm using the default built-in python (2.7.2) on 12.4.0, and I get a 64 bit maxint.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I run the Python under the directory "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current" and get a 32 bit maxint....

Comment: What does the startup banner say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are really running the Python you think you are.
`cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` doesn't help by itself.  If you did not change any of the default installer options, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` should now be first in your shell `PATH` (you need to open a new terminal window after installing to see this) and there should now be `python` and `python2.7` links in `/usr/local/bin` to the new Python.

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Actually, I do enter the directory with the command " cd  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin" and launch python with the command "./python". When executing the python above, I get the same result in my question. But after I reinstall the python, everything works fine though I don't know why. Thanks.