# Python Random Number Generator numpy_rng.random_integers(1e10)) OverflowError

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to generate random numbers in Python 2.7 on 64-bit Windows system through the following line of code:

```
random_state=numpy_rng.random_integers(1e10)
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long.
```

with the following trace back
   rand_num_generator = numpy.random.RandomState(random_state)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 618, in mtrand.RandomState.**init** (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:8275)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 654, in mtrand.RandomState.seed (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:8670)
ValueError: Seed must be between 0 and 4294967295

Comment: I am not sure if you already know this but it is not the random integer that can't be too large, it is the seed. Is there any specific reason you are using that large of a seed?

Comment: Sorry yes you are right its a seed. Actually its a a code from the net that i am trying to run on my system . Does seed do anything else other than setting the starting value of the random number?

Comment: No, just the initial value. You can use another number, it doesn't have to be that big.

Answer (score 2):

Max integer in your Python is:

```
import sys

sys.maxint
Out[61]: 2147483647
```

Or appr. `2.1e9`. That's limitation of Windows. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3411134/5510499) post:

> In their infinitive wisdom Microsoft has decided to make the 'long' C
>   type always a 32 bit signed integer - even on 64bit systems.

So, you can't use `random_integers` with arguments more than that number. You can use instead this trick:

```
10 * np.random.random_integers(1e9) - np.random.choice(10)
Out[62]: 3910179327L
```

Approach of @2Cubed with `randint(0, 1e10)` also should work, cause through `randint` python successfully convert `int` to `long`.

Comment: @ Vadim . thanx for the reply. But sorry i couldn't understand the trick because the range is still not 1e10

Comment: The code was Ok, it gives integer in `range(1, 1e10+1)`.

Comment: I rollbacked the code. And what is the error? `OverflowError` or `ValueError: Seed must be between 0 and 4294967295`.

Comment: Following is the complete  traceback   rand_num_generator = numpy.random.RandomState(random_state)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 618, in mtrand.RandomState.__init__ (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:8275)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 654, in mtrand.RandomState.seed (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:8670)
ValueError: Seed must be between 0 and 4294967295

Comment: You should use `seed ` for obtaining repeatable result. If you use `seed` > 4294967295, that means you want to have more than 4294967296 repeatable sequences. If so, it's better to post another question like "how to get quantity of repeatable results in range more than numpy.seed lets". Otherwise, recheck your code. Maybe you don't need `seed` at all?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, using NumPy.

```
from numpy.random import randint

randint(1e10)
# 6073545190
```

You may also use the built-in `random.randint` to accomplish the same task, with differences between this and the `numpy.random.randint` function described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7030595/6119465).

```
from random import randint

randint(0, 1e10)
# 7978154001
```

Comment: I tried the above mentioned code but still i am getting the same error

Comment: I tried the above mentioned code but still i am getting the same.For the 2nd line of code  it has following error errorValueError: Seed must be between 0 and 4294967295

Comment: @ATIF: Strange. Could you update your question with the entire stack trace, please?

Comment: Yes sure i have added the entire stack trace