# Why does Python detect windows 10 as win32

Tags: python, windows-10

I'm running windows 10 on AMD threadripper 16core and i have couple of python versions. The problem is when i run python , it detects my windows 10 as win32 not as 64bit OS. The python itself is 2.7.14 - 64bit. Anyone know what is wrong ?

[image]

Comment: [Check this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411079/why-does-the-python-2-7-amd-64-installer-seem-to-run-python-in-32-bit-mode)

Comment: "Win32" is just the name of the API, it applies to 64 bit Windows as well.