# I'm looking for gevent for Python 2.7 for windows

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets

However gevent depends upon greenlet and the .msi version I found fails to install and the egg for 2.6 refuses to install.

The msi version fails as follows.

```
C:\Windows\system32>easy_install greenlet
install_dir C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\
Searching for greenlet
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet/
Reading http://bitbucket.org/ambroff/greenlet
Reading http://undefined.org/python/#greenlet
Best match: greenlet 0.3.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/greenlet/greenlet-0.3.1.tar.gz#md5=8d75d7f3f659e915e286e1b0fa0e1c4d
Processing greenlet-0.3.1.tar.gz
Running greenlet-0.3.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\ian\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-1epg28\greenlet-0.3.1\egg-dist-tmp-mqhu3n
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'repository'
  warnings.warn(msg)
greenlet.c
greenlet.c : fatal error C1074: 'IDB' is illegal extension for PDB file:
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

C:\Windows\system32>
```

I guess this means that I have a wrong version of VS.

Is there anything else I can use?

I want to get PyQt4 so the GUI won't lock up if the database can't be reached or takes ages to reply.

Comment: I found what I needed at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Thanks for that link!  Hopefully the maintainer will put something official on PyPI, but this is great in the meantime.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

1. Grab the gevent installer from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
2. Install greenlet from that same site

And if you're on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine and are having trouble installing, [read this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652625/installing-setuptools-on-64-bit-windows/3652687#3652687).

Answer (score 5):

You should ask the maintainer of greenlet to build .msi for Python 2.7.

I did it here: [greenlet issue #17](https://bitbucket.org/ambroff/greenlet/issue/17/windows-installer-for-python-27)

**Update:** There are now builds for Python 2.7 on PyPI: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet

Answer (score 2):

I've got latest version from here - http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/detail?name=gevent-1.0a3.win32-py2.7.msi

There is .exe too. Look for both installer and .exe here - http://code.google.com/p/gevent/updates/list