# Python: Installing pip on Windows "Python Version 2.7 required which was not found in the registry"

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pip onto windows, but I keep getting the following error:

"Python Version 2.7 required which was not found in the registry"

I've looked around for a solution and I have checked to see if the registry value was in:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.6\InstallPath

as recommended in this post: [Installing SetupTools on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652625/installing-setuptools-on-64-bit-windows)

It's present in that register. So I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I just copied that from the other post......It's 2.7 in my path

Answer (score 3):

I made this reg file and imported it (assuming that your python is in "c:\python27"):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Help]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Help\Main Python Documentation]
@="C:\\Python27\\Doc\\python276.chm"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath]
@="C:\\Python27\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\InstallGroup]
@="Python 2.7"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Modules]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath]
@="C:\\Python27\\Lib;C:\\Python27\\DLLs;C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk"
```

hope this helps you (don't forget to restart after you do it...)