# How to use binary python installers for a mismatching python version?

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I need to run a 64bit binary python installer for windows (reportlab‑2.7.win‑amd64‑py2.6.exe) downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

Unfortunately, I have 64bit python 2.7 installed and can't switch to python 2.6. For compatibility reasons, I also can't switch to the reportlabs package for python 2.7. I am sure that the python 2.6 package is compatible with python 2.7.

The .exe installer won't install since it does not find python 2.6 in the registry. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087995/1731520) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652687/1731520), I created the following registry file code to set the required registry keys.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.6]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.6\InstallPath]
@="C:\\Python27"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.6\PythonPath]
@="C:\\Python27;C:\\Python27\\Lib\\;C:\\Python27\\DLLs\\"
```

Save this as a `.reg` file (e.g. "file.reg") and run it.

Basically, this file stores in the registry that python 2.6 is installed in the python 2.7 folders. You may have to adapt the paths.

After the registry keys were set, I was able to install the 64bit reportlabs package using the binary installer for python 2.6 with a python 2.7 installation. I didn't encounter any compatibility issues.

If you want to use this way for 32bit python, see the above mentioned posts.