# No module named setuptools

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

I want to install setup file of twilio. When I install it through given command it is given me an error:

> No module named setuptools.

Could you please let me know what should I do?

I am using `python 2.7`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Python27>python D:\test\twilio-twilio-python-26f6707\setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\twilio-twilio-python-26f6707\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Comment: ...but the title can be easily googled... and my favourite answer is currently [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12793230/2932052)

Comment: I'm voting for reopen since I have this problem on Ubuntu 14.04 and it is not due to a x86 / x64 conflict of the installer. In short I simply needed to install pip - `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: For anyone else that had same issue I had: I had this problem trying to run the setup.py script for the Azure walinuxagent.

Answer (score 119):

Install [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and try again.

try command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools
```

Comment: I was going to vote you down for not providing the command to install setuptools but you really do need to go to that URL to see how to install it on your specific system.

Comment: Debian/ubuntu: `apt-get install -y python-setuptools`

Comment: This issue came up when optimizing a docker build file with `apt install --no-install-recommends ...`

Answer (score 55):

For ubuntu users, this error may arise because setuptool is not installed system-wide. Simply install setuptool using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools
```

For python3:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools
```

After that, install your package again normally, using

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

That's all.

Comment: For Python 3, use `sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools`.

Comment: I still get "ImportError: No module named setuptools". I also opened a new command shell.

Answer (score 18):

For Python Run This Command

```
apt-get install -y python-setuptools
```

For Python 3.

```
apt-get install -y python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 15):

The [PyPA recommended](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) tool for installing and managing Python packages is `pip`. `pip` is included with Python 3.4 ([PEP 453](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/)), but for older versions here's [how to install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) it (on Windows, using Python 3.3):

Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

```
>c:\Python33\python.exe get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
Downloading/unpacking setuptools
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools
Successfully installed pip setuptools
Cleaning up...
```

Sample usage:

```
>c:\Python33\Scripts\pip.exe install pymysql
Downloading/unpacking pymysql
Installing collected packages: pymysql
Successfully installed pymysql
Cleaning up...
```

In your case it would be this (it appears that `pip` caches independent of Python version):

```
C:\Python27>python.exe \code\Python\get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |################################| 69kB 255kB/s
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.29.0

C:\Python27>cd Scripts

C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install twilio
Collecting twilio
  Using cached twilio-5.3.0.tar.gz
Collecting httplib2>=0.7 (from twilio)
  Using cached httplib2-0.9.2.tar.gz
Collecting six (from twilio)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from twilio)
  Using cached pytz-2015.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: twilio, httplib2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for twilio ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Cees.Timmerman\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\e0\f2\a7\c57f6d153c440b93bd24c1243123f276dcacbf43cc43b7f906
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for httplib2 ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Cees.Timmerman\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\e1\a3\05\e66aad1380335ee0a823c8f1b9006efa577236a24b3cb1eade
Successfully built twilio httplib2
Installing collected packages: httplib2, six, pytz, twilio
Successfully installed httplib2-0.9.2 pytz-2015.7 six-1.10.0 twilio-5.3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

For python3 is:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

The question mentions Windows, and the accepted answer also works for Ubuntu, but for those who found this question coming from a Redhat flavor of Linux, this did the trick:

```
sudo yum install -y python-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Specific Version:

```
pip install python-setuptools
```

Upgrade  python-setuptools

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade python-setuptools
```

Getting Dependency Error in Window 10
Use code: easy_install instead of pip install

```
easy_install python-setuptools
```

Upgrade using easy install

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade  python-setuptools
```

On OSX System to install Module:
Use code: brew install instead of pip install

```
brew install python-setuptools
```

Without Using Pip :

```
 sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools
```

On CentOS7 or Linux Fedora:

```
yum -y install python-setuptools
```

Or on Fedora try

```
sudo dnf install python-setuptools
```

Command if Homebrew screws up your path on macOS:

```
python -m pip install python-setuptools
```

For Python3 MacOs Homebrew screws

```
python3 -m pip install python-setuptools
```

Verify module from list MacOs

```
pip freeze | grep  python-setuptools
```

For Execute on Anaconda as your python package manager

```
 conda install -c anaconda python-setuptools
```