# How to run a python (django) app on my internet server?

Tags: python, django

Yesterday I finished the tutorial for Django framework. 
On this tutorial I've created simple application and now I'd like to move my app to remote internet server. I have such server , I'm connected to SSH by putty and when I write `python`, I see: `Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19)`

But if I try to put this commend: `python setup.py install`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import find_packages, setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

and it's strange because after this:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
```

I see the version: `(1, 10, 5, u'final', 0)`

And I copied a folder with my app by FTP

So, can you tell me, step by step, how can I run my application?

---

Thanks for your answers. I've tried this code:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

and i received this message:

> sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with
>   the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named setuptools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531360/no-module-named-setuptools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Debian based system, try running:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

to install Python `setuptools` package

If you're not on a Debian based system, look at the package installing guide [here](https://packaging.python.org/installing/).

Comment: @python_b Just become root somehow. Depending on your distribution, try `su`. Then run `apt-get install python-setuptools`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). Install it and the error will be gone.