# Issue while installing Newrelic

Tags: marklogic, newrelic, newrelic-platform

It looks like the URL provided in Setup.py file of Newrelic plugin is obsolete.
Every time I try to run ***python setup.py install*** , I get following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in 
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools

But setuptools package is well installed in the system.

Can anybody please help how to deal with it.

Note: There is nothing wrong with setuptools or python here. It is Setup.py file of newRelic that has the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531360/no-module-named-setuptools)

Comment: Looks like this has been filed as an issue on the [NewRelic plugin site on GitHub](https://github.com/marklogic-community/newrelic-plugin/issues/25).

Comment: Yes @DaveCassel , but still no solution from the github contributor
Even nothing has been mentioned if there are any changes to it or not