# Python : setuptools module is already installed but still shows import error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install something using "python setup.py install" but it shows me this error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I have installed this missing module using "pip install setuptools". But still it shows me the same error .I have also tried to install this using "sudo apt-get install python-setuptools" but the problem still remains the same. Help me in this issue

Comment: Do you have another version of python installed or only 2.7?

Comment: [No module named setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531360/no-module-named-setuptools)

Comment: @Szabolcs i have python3 installed as well

Comment: @Siva I saw this but it did not helped me

Comment: can you check what happens when you do `import setuptools` both in your python2 and python3 interpreter?

Comment: @Szabolcs it gets imported in python3 but not in python2

Comment: @priyanshagrawal did you try `sudo pip2 install setuptools` or `pip install -U pip setuptools`?

Comment: @Siva Everytime i do "sudo pip install <modulename>"

Comment: @priyanshagrawal `sudo pip2 install setuptools` should work in that case. Else can you post the result after installing the setuptools ?

Comment: @Siva it shows me this :- Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: @priyanshagrawal what is output of `which python` ? is it also pointing to python2.7 ?

Comment: @Siva /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: @priyanshagrawal then the version of python in which you are importing should be the problem. In command line try `>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)` and make sure it shows 2.7.X and import `>>> import setuptools`

Comment: @Siva yes this shows me the python 2.7.14 but shows importError for setuptools . So am i having some problem in my python2.7 ? should i Reinstall it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4   installed from python.org, you will already have  pip and setuptools, but will need to upgrade to the latest version:

On Linux or macOS:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

On Windows:

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

If you’re using a Python install on Linux that’s managed by the system package manager (e.g “yum”, “apt-get” etc…), and you want to use the system package manager to install or upgrade pip, then see [link](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#installing-pip-setuptools-wheel-with-linux-package-managers)

Comment: I already have my pip and setuptools module in the latest version ...anyway thanks to have look into my problem