# fresh installed pip with get-pip.py no module found setuptools

Tags: python, pip

I can't get it. This happens me first time with fresh installed pip.
through `python3 get-pip.py`
Instead `~/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` its defaults to (because of user permissions) to `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`
I am getting `no module setuptools found` after triggering `sudo python3 setup.py install`
on my program even If my pip lists setuptools as module. I think that problem is path because when I installed ez-setup.py setuptools version something 0.30 instead default provided by pip manually it founds. Or do you know another reason why its didn't found my setuptools?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing setuptools system-wide?
You can try running

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools
```

And after

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

This can be helpful: [No module named setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531360/no-module-named-setuptools/50931314)