# Seaborn ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am getting the `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found`. when importing the module seaborn.

My code is:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
```

Output:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-6f477838ac7f> in <module>
----> 1 import seaborn

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>
      1 # Capture the original matplotlib rcParams
----> 2 import matplotlib as mpl
      3 _orig_rc_params = mpl.rcParams.copy()
      4 
      5 # Import seaborn objects

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    205 
    206 
--> 207 _check_versions()
    208 
    209 

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in _check_versions()
    190     # Quickfix to ensure Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable
    191     # DLLs are loaded before importing kiwisolver
--> 192     from . import ft2font
    193 
    194     for modname, minver in [

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled seaborn. still problem is not solved. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I just got your issue with both seaborn and matplotlib. Did you try executing matplotlib ? Searching for an answer, I found out that it might be related to the matplotlib actual version (3.3.1). Here's the StackOverflow post that helped me.

[from matplotlib import ft2font: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251102/from-matplotlib-import-ft2font-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-pro)

I just deleted/uninstalled matplotlib from my current packages (I work in a virtual env), and reinstalled a previous version (3.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with importing seaborn in jupyter lab, lately.

I uninstalled the seaborn using pip:

`pip uninstall seaborn`

Then installed it again using pip:

`pip install seaborn`

This worked in my case.

Just on the sidenote, I also updated the whole conda enviroment using
`conda update --all`. But this might not be influential in this case.