# vim: how to set up py.exe as python interpreter

Tags: python, windows, vim, portability

I'm using *vim* and multiple *python* versions (2.7, 3.3) on *windows* at my work without administrative privileges. Earlier i used *[portablepython](http://portablepython.com/)* which is ok to run the program which i working on, but it dropped me warning messages when i opened a *python* script in *vim* while *[jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim)* was installed (i think the occurred by the modified `python27.dll`). So i installed *python* at home (with the option "just for me"), copied it to *dropbox* and downloaded to work pc and set up [registry keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087995/2520275) and the `PATH` variable. The *python* itself works fine (including the [python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)), but the *vim* plugins fails if `python33` is ahead of `python27` in the `PATH`.

Can is set up *vim* to use `py.exe` instead of `python.exe` as interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

For the `:python` integration into Vim, no Python executable is used. Instead, Vim must be compiled with support for a particular Python version, and that DLL must then be accessible through `PATH` during runtime. (It can also be statically linked, but the `+python/dyn` is the default on Windows.)

Therefore, it is crucial that the correct `pythonXXX.dll` version can be located through `PATH`, as you've already found out.

Comment: "plugins fails if python33 is ahead of python27 in the PATH" - so all of the _dll_s is in the `PATH`, but the order takes precedence over the version i think, because _vim_ fails to load the right version of _python_.