# Installing 64 bit pygame on to python 2.7, 'python version 2.7 required'

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, pygame

I recently downloaded the unofficial 64 bit version of pygame from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and tried installing it. While going through the process, it tells me 'Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry.' and fails the installation. I'm currently running python 2.7.8 64 bit, and I don't know why it's refusing to install.

Comment: Are you running on windows or linux ? is your version of python in your PATH ? try running in the terminal just "python -v" and see if it can find your version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please re-install python cause I think your python has some fault. then try to install pygame again.

OR

better install pygame 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by executing a [registry adding program](https://sites.google.com/site/joedfdev/files/hidden/python27patch_x64.reg?attredirects=0) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652625/installing-setuptools-on-64-bit-windows/9131949#9131949).