# How to build Apache WebSocket module?

Tags: python, apache, websocket, scons, cl

I was trying for many hours to solve this. I have found [Apache-WebSocket](https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket) from [Disconnect](https://github.com/disconnect) and decided to try this out. The description recommends [Scons](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scons/?source=typ_redirect). However, to be able to use Scons, I need [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) as well. I installed the newest 3.x+ Python, but when I installed Scons as well and tried to build the module, it told me that Python 3.x+ is not supported yet. Ok, I uninstalled both Scons and Python, then installed Python 2.7.7.

After I have done that, I faced further difficulties, since Python was not found in the Registry. After a search I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652625/installing-setuptools-on-64-bit-windows/9131949#9131949). I extracted and executed the file. After that, Scons worked, but still failed to install the module.

After looking into SConstruct, I have seen there is a hard-coded path for Apache and I have fixed the path. After that, I ran the following command in the folder:

```
scons install
```

but the response was this:

> ```
> scons: Reading SConscript files ...
> scons: done reading SConscript files.
> scons: Building targets ...
> cl /Fomod_websocket.obj /c mod_websocket.c /nologo /O2 /MD /EHsc /W3 /DWIN32 /IC
> :\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\include
> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> scons: *** [mod_websocket.obj] Error 1
> scons: building terminated because of errors.
> ```

I am using Windows 8 and Wamp. What should I do to fix the problem I am facing?

EDIT:

This great page helped me to solve the problem with cl. I needed to install common tools for Visual C++ and then I needed to run

```
vcvarsall.bat x86
```

After that I have executed

```
scons install
```

and it passed the point it failed the last time. Now the new error is as follows:

> ```
> mod_websocket.so.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the
>  manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.
> scons: *** [mod_websocket.so] Error 31
> scons: building terminated because of errors.
> ```

Comment: A couple questions:  Which version of SCons? Which version of visual Studio?  You should not have to run vcvarsall.bat x86 on your system before installing scons. SCons should find the installed visual studio.

Comment: Scons 2.5.0. Visual Studio 2015. Scons was already installed when I executed vcvarsall.bat

Comment: It shouldn't matter when you install Visual Studio relative to when you install SCons. SCons should locate Visual Studio each time it is run.   Can you try the following:  don't run vcvarsall.bat, set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=%TEMPDIR%\scons_mstrace.log , run scons, and then pastebin the output somewhere and add it to your question?

Comment: @bdbaddog, the last error in the question is related to the manifest. All the steps before that were completed successfully. My question is: does your idea address the issue shown about the manifest?

Comment: As I said in my previous comment. You shouldn't need to run vcvarsall.bat prior to running SCons.   If you needed to it indicates that SCons didn't find your Visual studio install.  This is where setting SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG would help figure out why it failed, and relieve the need to run vcvarsall.bat.    It is possible that incomplete initialization of MSVC, and MSVC in scons could be related to your remaining issue.

Comment: @bdbaddog, thank you, I will check that out when I can and will write a feedback about it.

Comment: @bdbaddog, can you convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter when you install Visual Studio relative to when you install SCons. SCons should locate Visual Studio each time it is run. Can you try the following: don't run vcvarsall.bat,

> set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=%TEMPDIR%\scons_mstrace.log

run scons, and then pastebin the output somewhere and add it to your question?

You shouldn't need to run vcvarsall.bat prior to running SCons. If you needed to it indicates that SCons didn't find your Visual studio install. This is where setting SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG would help figure out why it failed, and relieve the need to run vcvarsall.bat. It is possible that incomplete initialization of MSVC, and MSVC in scons could be related to your remaining issue.

Can you pastebin the generated logfile?

Comment: This makes sense and is probably true. I have resolved the problem alternatively, but I believe this answer deserves to be accepted. When I get back to this issue I might revoke the acceptation if there is a problem I encounter.