# Python 2.4.3 on Red Hat 4.1.2-51 MemoryError on list.append(new) but only using 9 Gb out of 32 Gb of ram

Tags: python, memory, ram

4.3 on Red Hat 4.1.2-51 MemoryError on list.append(new) but only using 9 Gb out of 32 Gb of ram

I am not sure how to check if my python is compiled with 64 bit I assume that I am using 9 Gb so it shouldn't be that issue. 
for java I think u can specify the ram to be used with a jar. Is there a default limit for python?

how would I solve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1405913/589206). Citation:

```
python -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
```

and check the result.

Comment: `$ python -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'`

gives this 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maxsize'
$ python
Python 2.3.4 (#1, Apr 15 2011, 17:38:51) 
[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

Comment: `$ python -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'` gives me 64 though so the python is 64 bit