# Homebrew failing to install postgresql; python 64-bit errors

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, homebrew

I'm getting errors when running

`$ brew install postgresql`

```
==> Downloading http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.1.2/postgresql-9.1.2.tar.bz2
File already downloaded in /Users/neil/Library/Caches/Homebrew
Warning: Detected a framework Python that does not have 64-bit support in:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python

e configure script seems to prefer this version of Python over any others,
 you may experience linker problems as described in:
http://osdir.com/ml/pgsql-general/2009-09/msg00160.html

 fix this issue, you may need to either delete the version of Python
own above, or move it out of the way before brewing PostgreSQL.

te that a framework Python in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework is
e "MacPython" version, and not the system-provided version which is in:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
==> ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2 --datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/shar
^C
```

---

Here's where python is located.

`$ which python`

`/usr/local/bin/python`

---

I modified my ~/.zshrc PATH from

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

to

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

---

And although I'm getting python 64-bit errors, my version of python is 64-bit according to this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode):

`$ python -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'`

`64`

Answer (score 2):

The problem pointed out in the [referenced mailing list post](http://osdir.com/ml/pgsql-general/2009-09/msg00160.html) is that the configure step isn't impacted by the PATH here.  There's a whole other mechanism used to find things to link against; see [Where do I set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/282450/where-do-i-set-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-is-it-a-good-idea) for a quick intro.  You could try the suggested workaround given by the brew script--rename */Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python* to something else to get it out of the linker's search path, repeat the brew install, then put it back.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need Python bindings in your PostgreSQL, you can also just install it without Python bindings using `brew install postgresql --no-python`.

Answer (score 0):

This command is installing the server, not the python bindings. Is that what you want? There is a [installer for osx](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) that will install the server for you.

Once you have done that, you can install the psycopg2 bindings [directly from source](http://blog.jonypawks.net/2008/06/20/installing-psycopg2-on-os-x/).

Comment: [Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-postgresql#macintosh) recommends using homebrew to use PostgreSQL for local Rails development. I do not understand why python bindings are being installed.

Comment: Homebrew includes python, ruby, and other language bindings by default when installing a program or server, instead of providing them as separate packages. So the 'postgresql' package includes the server, the client, and language bindings.