# How to check if Windows is 32 or 64 bits on Python2.2

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, x86-64

In python2.7 it's simple, just import the lib platform. But how can i see if my windows is 32 or 64 bits? I work with a system build in python2.2 and can't find a way of do that :(

Any sugestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using Python 2.2? It's more than 10 years old and the new versions are as free as the old ones.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that checks whether the interpreter was built in 32-bits or 64-bits mode. It doesn't tell you much about the OS.

Comment: :/ Because i work in a company that still use the python2.2 on our major application, i know it's sucks :/. @larsmans

Comment: @larsmans: you *may* have a 32-bit python interpreter on a 64-bit platform, but you cannot make that work the other way around. Thus, the two usually correlate.

Comment: No access to Windows at this time, but have you looked at the [os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) or [sys module](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html)?  Maybe [sys.platform](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform) or [os.name](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.name)?

Comment: @sshekhar: Note the top of that document you linked to: *New in version 2.3.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`platform` module](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/platform.py) is informative.

Backported from there to determine the machine architecture on a Windows platform, it would use:

```
import os

def machine():
    try:
        return os.uname()[-1]
    except AttributeError:
        if "PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432" in os.environ:
            return os.environ.get("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432", '')
        else:
            return os.environ.get('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x you can do this:

```
import sys
print sys.maxint
```

And detect if it's 32/64 bit by `sys.maxint`.

**Notice:** this method may probably fail if you're running a 32 bit Python on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Is that not dependent on the build of Python itself and not the OS?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Yes indeed. And I myself consider it as a `well, can it be worse?` answer.