# psycopg2 install fails because gcc-4.0 is missing, even though gcc-4.2 is available

Tags: gcc, psycopg2

Sorry for this basic question. I am new to this and I have been pulling my hair out.

**Environment:**

- Python2.7.3 + Django 1.4 + PostgreSQL 9.2.
- OSX 10.8.2 + Xcode 4.5.1

**Error:**

I tried to install psycopg2 in different ways: from source, easy_install and pip. I always get the same error: unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory + error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

I first did not have gcc installed so downloaded Xcode and the related developer tools. Now I have gcc-4.2. This is the version: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1

BUT psycopg2 keeps insisting on gcc-4.0, but I (now) have 4.2. At the same time, I have noticed from other Stackoverflow posts that it is possible to compile psycopg2 using gcc-4.2. And I'd rather not do one of these unsupported hacks involving Xcode3 in order to access Gcc-4.0.

**My question**:

Can I specify to use gcc-4.2, instead of gcc-4.0 somehow when installing psycopg2? Django + PostgreSQL are very commonly used so surely there must be a simple way to solve this? Many thanks!!

Comment: Is PostgreSQL compiled with gcc-4.0 or 4.2?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I am not sure. I downloaded the 9.2.1 OSX version [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx) During the installation process, it didn't mention anything about gcc either. I get the error when installing psycopg2, e.g. pip install psycopg2 . Tx!!!

Comment: That's probably it then. One of PostgreSQL or Python is built using gcc-4.0 so that's what it wants to build add-ons with. So long as they all use the same it shouldn't matter which. It might even be safe to just override the check, but I can't guarantee that. Oh - "pg_config" is a useful way to get some details of how your PostgreSQL setup was built.

Comment: Thanks @Richard my version of Python 2.7.3 was indeed built using gcc-4.0. and therefore it was forcing this (older) gcc version on the psycopg2 install. For the benefit of others with the same problem: upgrading my python install from a 32bit to 64bit [version] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode) solved it. Just updating the CC variable did not work.

Comment: Installing Python 2.7.3 64-bit worked for me as well.  http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/