# Python on MacOS totally ignoring rlimit

Tags: python, macos, resources, setrlimit

My Python process on MacOS is totally ignoring the rlimits below which I set.
(I confirmed by print that they have been set)

Physical memory usage goes above 2.4Gb, at which point CPU usage falls << 5% and it hangs.
(The underlying culprit seems to be numpy array allocation, but I can't force an `OutOfMemory` exception to pinpoint where, so I'm stuck). What's going on? I thought hard rlimits cannot be ignored?

EDIT: it occurs to me that the offending allocation is not being done in native Python, but in either numpy or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/). Link to [source of cpython:Modules/resource.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/02a89bd646ca/Modules/resource.c) If so, that would be a definite docbug.

```
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS,    (1*1048576L, 1.2*1048576L))
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_DATA,  (1*1048576L, 1.1*1048576L))
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (100000, 120000))
```

Versions: python2.7.3 (macports, [64b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode)) on MacOS 10.8.2, py27-numpy.

Machine has 4Gb physical RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs to me that the offending allocation is not being done in native Python, but in either numpy or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/).
My allocation code may be leaking memory to temporaries. Will investigate. May need to look at the [gc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html).

If this is the case, that sounds like a docbug on [resource](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html).

Link to [source of cpython:Modules/resource.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/02a89bd646ca/Modules/resource.c)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Chromium issue #853873](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=853873#c2), macOS does not *(at least as recently as mid-2018)* respect `RLIMIT_DATA` or `RLIMIT_AS`.