# Dot product of huge arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a huge array and I want to calculate dot product with a small array. But I am getting 'array is too big' Is there a work around?

```
import numpy as np

eMatrix = np.random.random_integers(low=0,high=100,size=(20000000,50))
pMatrix = np.random.random_integers(low=0,high=10,size=(50,50))

a = np.dot(eMatrix,pMatrix)

Error:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so in mtrand.RandomState.random_integers (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:9385)()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:7051)()

ValueError: array is too big.
```

Comment: This happens already at eMatrix =, no? You are asking for 10^9 integers - one GB times the number of bytes per integer. So at the very least you should put them into an array of dtype int8 rather than the default int64.

Comment: But I have a 64 bit machine having 16GB RAM

Comment: So 8GB for the first ePrime, at least the same again for a, and perhaps some unseen intermediate ones too.

Answer (score 3):

That error is raised when figuring the total size of the array, if it overflows the native int type, [see here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L962) for the exact source code line.

For this to happen, regardless of your machine being 64 bits, you are almost certainly running 32 bit versions of Python (and NumPy). [You can check if that is the case by doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize
2147483647 # <--- 2**31 - 1, on a 64 bit version you would get 2**63 - 1
```

Then again, you array is "only" `20000000 * 50 = 1000000000`, which is just under `2**30`. If I try to reproduce your results on a 32-bit numpy, I get a `MemoryError`:

```
>>> np.random.random_integers(low=0,high=100,size=(20000000,50))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1420, in mtrand.RandomState.random_integers (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:12943)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 938, in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:10338)
MemoryError
```

unless I increase the size beyond the magic `2**31 - 1` threshold

```
>>> np.random.random_integers(low=0,high=100,size=(2**30, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1420, in mtrand.RandomState.random_integers (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:12943)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 938, in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:10338)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

Given the difference in the line numbers in your traceback and mine, I suspect you are using an older version. What does this output on your system:

```
>>> np.__version__
'1.10.0.dev-9c50f98'
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I am using numpy version 1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

I think the only "simple" answer is get more RAM.

It took 15GB, but I was able to do this on my macbook.

```
In [1]: import numpy
In [2]: e = numpy.random.random_integers(low=0, high=100, size=(20000000, 50))
In [3]: p = numpy.random.random_integers(low=0, high=10, size=(50, 50))
In [4]: a = numpy.dot(e, p)
In [5]: a[0]
Out[5]:
array([14753, 12720, 15324, 13588, 16667, 16055, 14144, 15239, 15166,
       14293, 16786, 12358, 14880, 13846, 11950, 13836, 13393, 14679,
       15292, 15472, 15734, 12095, 14264, 12242, 12684, 11596, 15987,
       15275, 13572, 14534, 16472, 14818, 13374, 14115, 13171, 11927,
       14226, 13312, 16070, 13524, 16591, 16533, 15466, 15440, 15595,
       13164, 14278, 13692, 12415, 13314])
```

A possible solution might be using a [sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) and the sparse matrix dot operator.

For example, on my machine constructing just `e` as a dense matrix used 8GB of ram.  Constructing a similar sparse matrix `eprime`:

```
In [1]: from scipy.sparse import rand
In [2]: eprime = rand(20000000, 50)
```

Has neglible cost in terms of memory.

Comment: I believe once you do a calculation like dot, you'll have a dense matrix again.

Comment: Hey @stderr as I mentioned above I too tried it on mac having 16GB ram but it is failing.

Comment: Also I don't want a sparse matrix, my matrix needs to be dense

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is you do not have enough RAM and also possibly you are running a 32 bit version of python. Maybe clarify what OS you are running. Many OSes will run both 32 and 64 bit programs.

Comment: How do I check if I am running 32 bit version of python?

Comment: As stated above see here on how to determine if you are running 64 bit or 32 bit python executable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os