# Error importing sklearn (scikit learn package) in python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to import datasets from sklearn package using following code

```
from sklearn import datasets
```

I get the error log

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 213, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have installed the following modules:

- numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win32.whl
- scikit_learn-0.16.1-cp34-none-win32.whl
- scipy-0.16.0-cp34-none-win32.whl

from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

How do i resolve this issue? I am using python 3.4. Please help.

Comment: I'd say the following additional information would be relevant: Is your windows using a 32 or 64-bit architecture? Are you using 32 or 64-bit python (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os)? Apart from that I'd recommend you to look at [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/) to see if it fits your needs. It makes the installation process easier.

Comment: Platform being used is '32bit', and the python I am using is 32 bit as well. I ll definitely take a look at Anaconda. Thank you.

Comment: As it is said on your link it is unofficial libraries. should should consider using official ones to be sure they correctly linked together.