# Library not loaded: /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, osx-elcapitan, cx-oracle

I have export `$ORACLE_HOME` set to the directory containing all the instance client files. And LD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set to `$ORACLE_HOME/` in my `~/.bash_profile`.

I just can't seem to get past this error when I try import cx_Oracle in python:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Library not loaded: /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
Reason: image not found
```

My Environment:

- OS X El Capitan - 10.11.2
- Python: 2.7
- Oracle Instant Client - 64-bit:

  - instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
  - instantclient-basic-macos.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip

I can connect to the Oracle database using sqlplus without any issue.

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259671/how-to-install-cx-oracle-on-el-capitan), but didn't help either.

Comment: Have You managed to solve this problem? I am having the same issue on osx El Captian 10.11.3 (15D21)  and read already a lot possible fixes but non of them worked.

Comment: Yes, I was able to resolve this issue. The main thing I learnt especially with OSX is that you don't want to use the python version that comes with Mac OS. So, here's what I did.  1) Install Virtualenv 2) create a virtual env 3) install cx_Oracle 4) Make sure you have downloaded the oracle drivers and you have set Oracle_HOME in your ~/.bash_profile

Comment: How did you resolve it? I can import cx_Oracle directly in Python, connect via sqlplus, but I'm getting this error when trying to use cx_Oracle in django. Like you, I've set it all up in a virtualenv.

Comment: I found solution to problem very similar to this one on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231960/cx-oracle-importerror#35268217

Comment: In my case, what had happened is that I had reinstalled **instantClient**, going up from 11.2 to 12.1.   **cx-Oracle** (5.2) was installed when **instantClient** was 11.2.  `pip install cx-Oracle --upgrade` bounced **cx-Oracle** up to 5.3 and that problem went away.  And was promptly replaced by another - GRRRR Oracle -, but that's another story.