# Error importing pymssql

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, pymssql

I am trying to import pymssql and I am getting this error (I think I have installed it correctly):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymssql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymssql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _dbversion
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymssql.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The symbol was not found on import, possibly due to a linking problem at compilation when setup.py was run.

I ran into this particular issue because I was running 32-bit Python 2.7.12 on my OS X machine.  Doing the following resolved the issue for me:

- Making sure I had the right version of FreeTDS installed.  [Until pymssql 2.20 is released, pymssql is not compatible with FreeTDS 1.0](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/432).  You can install FreeTDS 0.91 on OS X with `brew uninstall freetds` and `brew install homebrew/versions/freetds091`
- Making sure I had the 64-bit version of Python 2.7.12 installed.  [This a quick way to verify if you're running python as 32 or 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os).  I used [the python.org installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/) instead of using `brew install python`
- Making sure I wasn't relying on a pip cache when installing pymssql.  Instead, I used `pip install --no-cache-dir pymssql`

You need FreeTDS for the build to succeed, and if you don't build with the proper architecture, it is possible you will run into this error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 2020 update: I don't think this solution is possible any longer:

[FreeTDS 0.91 is no longer available on homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/freetds) and [pymssql is no longer maintained, so version 2.20 will never happen](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668).

With the scuttling of pymssql, the real answer now is probably to stop using it.

Comment: uninstall and install freetds back helped.

```` brew install freetds ```