# Loading a big list of matrices into Python shell

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I have a file containing a really big list of matrices (i.e. lists of lists of integers), which I want to load into the python shell. The file content has the form

```
L = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], ... ]
```

so I tried to load it via "execfile(filename)". Unfortunately, I am running out of memory in that way. What am I doing wrong?

For comparison: The file size is about 2GB, while the machine has 100GB of memory. The matrices are of dimension like 1000x1000.

Comment: can you [edit] your post to show a small example of the file? `L = [ ...many big matrices... ]` doesn't cut it as a representative example.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes, of course. It is just a list of lists of lists of integers.

Comment: do you have a 64-bit python? or 32-bit? and 64 bit OS?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It is Python 2.7.6 on a 64 bit Linux (3.12.62-55-desktop).

Comment: okay but is it a 32-bit or 64-bit version of python?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm quite sure it is also 64 bit - just because it would not make much sense to install 32 bit python on a 64 bit OS. But to be sure: how can I find that out?

Comment: Just run python and check version and 32 64 bit type.

Comment: I get: `Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`, it's 64 bit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It seems on Linux the Python shell does not tell the bit architecture so easily. But using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1406849/3066306) I get 64 as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt using `ast.literal_eval`. If it doesn't work, I'll delete my answer but I think it's worth a shot:

```
import ast

with open("bigfile.txt") as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if not c:
            break
        if c=='=':
            # equals found, skip spaces if any
            while f.read(1)==" ":
                pass
            break

    # rewind to sync with non-whitespace char that we have consumed
    f.seek(f.tell()-1)

    L = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

basically, open the file, read char by char to skip the assignment (`literal_eval` doesn't evaluate assignments, only structures, a bit like `json`) and feed the rest of the huge file to the literal evaluator.

Since it's another mean of doing it, it may work, and as a bonus it's much safer than using `exec` or `eval`.

EDIT: since your comment stated that it still took a lot of memory, I suggest that you write data line by line so ast.literal_eval can evaluate each line as a vector, and you can put it in your matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your try! But unfortunately, it also consumes a huge amount of memory (80GB by now), and will surely run out of memory soon...

Comment: Since I am producing the file by myself (using another programming language), maybe I should give it another format? Would it help to put each matrix in a different line so that we can read (and parse) the file line by line?

Comment: yes, you could just dump the dimensions, then the values, line by line, without any brackets, or with brackets but line by line so `ast.literal_eval` can evaluate each line as a vector, and you can put it in your matrix.

Comment: It worked! Now I've put each matrix in a separate line and applied ast.literal_eval to each. This only takes 5GB of memory which is still a little bit strange but well enough.

Comment: excellent. I have edited my answer with the thing you tried and which worked for completeness.