# Properly install pyodbc

Tags: python, pip, pyodbc

All I want to do is install pyodbc. I am using python 3.4.4 and I can verify the installation is not correct since running `import pyodbc` causes the error `ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc'`. In my /Python/Scripts directory I have tried multiple times running `pip install pyodbc` which gives `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyodbc in c:\python34\
lib\site-packages` and after searching I believe that means it has already been installed.

Additionally I tried downloading the .whl file and installing it as `pip install pyodbc-4.0.17-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl` which gives `pyodbc-4.0.17-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`.

What am I not doing that I need to do in order to get it installed properly?

Comment: Wild guess based on the wheel message: are you using a 32-bit Python?

Comment: Nope, I am using 64 bit as best I can tell based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406210/1489990

Comment: And you don't have multiple Python installations either? You already tried `python -m pip install pyodbc` (that is, running pip as a module rather than a command)?

Comment: What version of pip are you on?