# opencv install on osx no suitable image error

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have followed this tutorial to install opencv: https://medium.com/@nuwanprabhath/installing-opencv-in-macos-high-sierra-for-python-3-89c79f0a246a

I have two different virtual environments setup.

On one cv2 works fine.
On the other one I get:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/.virtualenvs/py3cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/py3cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

the working interpreter shows:

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Dec 25 2017, 14:57:56) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
```

when I go into python.
when I run `import ctypes;print(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p))`
I get: `8`

The breaking one shows:

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

when I run `import ctypes;print(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p))`:
I get: `4`

any ideas what is going wrong?

output of `name -a`

```
Darwin MyMBP 17.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Fri Apr 13 19:32:32 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: The next line from the *Python* prompt would be helpful. The architecture of the *.so* file doesn't seem to match the one of the *Python* executable that tries to load it. Try running `file path_to_python_executable` (for both of your *VEnv*s) and also `file /Users/me/.virtualenvs/py3cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so`.

Comment: added i the next line

Comment: What's the architecture of your *OSX* ? Check that by typing in the shell: `uname -m` (or better: `uname -a`). Also in *Python* prompt (for both instances) add: `import ctypes;print(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p))`.

Comment: added in the architecture and the ctypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an *.so* (shared object) to be successfully loaded by an executable, their architectures must match (on *OSX*, this can be extended to: the *.so* must "contain" the executable's architecture - as an *.so* can bundle multiple architectures inside).

The *OpenCV* version that you installed is built for *Intel **064bit*** (*pc064*). That's why it works on the *064bit* *Python*, but doesn't on *032bit* one.

For more details on *Python* architecture, check [[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053286/4788546).
Also, [[SO]: Install win32com on MacOs and Linux (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030870/4788546) might contain some useful info.