# Use .so library for android in python

Tags: python, android-ndk, ctypes, .so

I need to use the .so library developed for android (jni) but i need to use it in python

Code for android:

```
package x2;

import android.os.Build;

import java.util.Base64;

public class X {
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("adlemx");
        }

        public static String m0do(String str) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(x01(str).getBytes());
            }
            return "";
        }

        public static native String x01(String str);
    }
```

I tried use ctypes

```
from ctypes import cdll

print(cdll.LoadLibrary("./adlemx.so"))
```

but I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\_Projects\DiaryBackend\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(cdll.LoadLibrary("./adlemx.so"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not an application Win32
```

Comment: 1st of all, check: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) for that error. 2nd: **an *Android* library can't be loaded in *Win***. So this is a duplicate of [\[SO\]: Install win32com on MacOs and Linux (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030870/4788546).

Answer (score -1):

try create file with name of library "adlemx.py"
and paste this code

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'adlemx.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

then import this file

Comment: same error, also i tried different architectures none works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is completely incorrect, as it points out to loading an **extension module**, while the question is loading a "regular" *.so*.