# convert ppt to pdf python 3.9 macos

Tags: macos, pdf, powerpoint, python-3.9, comtypes

How can I convert ppt file to pdf file, my os is macos and I use python 3.9.

```
import os
import sys
import ppt2pdf.main as pp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    input_file_path = dir_path + "/myppt.pptx"
    output_file_path = dir_path + "/mypdf.pdf"
    pp.convert(input_file_path, output_file_path)
```

but I got error as below
ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-darwin.so)

Comment: [\[SO\]: Install win32com on MacOs and Linux (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030870/4788546). You might want to search for another module.