# Unable to install pywin32 for python 3.9 application running on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I am curring building an aws lambda using python 3.9 and i want to install pywin32. when i run

```
pipenv install pywin32
```

i get the following error

```
Loading .env environment variables...
Installing pywin32...
Resolving pywin32...
Installing...
⠙ Installing pywin32...[31m[1mError: [0m An error occurred while installing [32mpywin32[0m!
Error text: 
[36mERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
[0m
✘ Installation Failed
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install win32com on MacOs and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975918/install-win32com-on-macos-and-linux)