# Python3 uses restype to define the return value of kernel32.GetModuleHandleA, but the value of python output is very large

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I am studying the book `"Python Grey Hat"`, this is one of my functions, I have been looking for this problem for a long time or not solved.

```
def func_resolve(self,dll,function):
    GetModuleHandle             = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA
    GetModuleHandle.argtypes    = [c_char_p]
    GetModuleHandle.restype     = c_void_p
    handle = GetModuleHandle(dll)
    print(handle)
    GetProcAddress              = kernel32.GetProcAddress
    GetProcAddress.argtypes     = [c_void_p,c_char_p]
    GetProcAddress.restype      = c_void_p
    address = GetProcAddress(handle,function)
    print(address)
```

My output handle value is `140707194077184`, the address value is `140707194386736`, I use OllyDbg to view the address of the wprintf function in msvcrt.dll is `0x73D178A0`, but the value of address is converted to hexadecimal is also much larger than `0x73D178A0`, hope Can someone help me, thank you

Comment: Can you specify *msvcrt.dll*' (that you mentioned) full path?

Comment: FYI, you should use `GetModuleHandleW` with Unicode `c_wchar_p`, especially in Python 3 where strings are Unicode. Also, you only have to define the prototypes once for the `kernel32` function pointers, not every time you call `func_resolve`. This works because the first time you look up the `GetModuleHandleW` attribute on `kernel32`, it caches the function-pointer object that gets created, so subsequent access uses the same object.

Comment: 'mscvrt.dll' absolute path I have tried, the effect is the same.

Comment: For the answer to eryksun, I originally used GetModuleHandleW and c_wchar_p, but the result is the same as now. You said that I first defined the prototype of GetModuleHandleW outside the function. I feel very good. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The return value is a Windows handle.  The value is big because you are using 64-bit Python.  The value doesn't matter as long as you've declared your ctypes properly.  This code will work Python 2 or 3, 32- or 64-bit, and uses `ctypes.wintypes` for predefined Windows types:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as w

print(sys.version)

kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32')

GetModuleHandle          = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
GetModuleHandle.argtypes = [w.LPCWSTR]
GetModuleHandle.restype  = w.HMODULE
GetProcAddress           = kernel32.GetProcAddress
GetProcAddress.argtypes  = [w.HMODULE,w.LPCSTR]
GetProcAddress.restype   = c_void_p  # FARPROC isn't defined in wintypes, but a generic pointer works.

handle = GetModuleHandle(u'user32')
address = GetProcAddress(handle,b'MessageBeep')
print(hex(address))
MessageBeep = WINFUNCTYPE(w.BOOL,w.UINT)(address)
MessageBeep(0)
```

Output with two Pythons I have installed (beep is played each time):

```
C:\>py -2 test.py
2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
0x756e56d0

C:\>py -3 test.py
3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
0x7fff6ca29a40
```

Comment: After reading your example and output, I looked at my python3 again and found that I was wrong. It turns out that my python3 is 64-bit. I blame me for being careful. If I see win32, I think it is 32-bit. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for clearly explaining the reason for the error and giving a solution. Is there any documentation which gives the argtypes and restypes or do we have to check the winapi documentation and infer the argtypes and restypes?

Comment: @AbhishekKishore You have to read the Windows documentation.  Some equivalent Windows types are defined in `ctypes.wintypes` such as `HANDLE`, `LPWSTR`, etc. so you don't have to infer.

Comment: @AbhishekKishore I updated the answer to demonstrate using the predefined Windows types.

Comment: I was unaware of wintypes.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind the answer to my comment, I've found the cause. From [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de) (**emphasis** is mine):

> OllyDbg is a **32-bit** assembler level analysing debugger for Microsoft<sup>®</sup> Windows<sup>®</sup>.

That means that it can only load (work with) *32 bit* processes (and / or *.dll*s) **only**. *wprintf* address confirms it (*0x**73D178A0*** is *32 bit* as it has (at most) **8** *hex* digits).

On the other hand, in *Python*, you get (much) larger values for pointers or addresses (e.g. *handler* = *140707194077184* (*0x**7FF8F256B930***)) which don't fit in the *32 bit* range, so it's *64 bit*. For more details on how to get running *Python* architecture, check [[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os/50053286#50053286) (even if the question is for *OSX*, *Win* is covered as well).

So, what's the catch? It's [[MS.Docs]: File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector) that confused you regarding *msvcr(t###).dll* location:

- *Python* (*64 bit*) loaded it from *"%windir%\**System32**"*
- *OllyDbg* (*32 bit*) made you think that it loaded it from the same location (for backward compatibility reasons), when in fact it loaded it from *"%windir%\**SysWOW64**"*

Using a tool built for both *32 bit* and *64 bit* that you can launch in parallel (I use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com)), you can see the differences.

Comment: My is windows10, my downloaded python3 is 32-bit

Comment: That's a common mistake.  Really check my answer.

Comment: Where should I download the dependency walker? I downloaded all the latest zips from the official website, but I will not respond when I open the dll file.

Comment: When I use OllDbg, I drag the dll directly from the c:\windows\system32 path, so the OllDbg should be loaded with c:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll. Now I use func_resolve, the dll parameter passed is the absolute path of 'msvcrt.dll', but the result is the same

Comment: Sorry, I typed python from the cmd command line to see it clearly. My python3 is 64-bit. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Do not worry. Common mistake, could happen to anyone :)