# Python psutil memory_info caps at 4.0G

Tags: python, psutil

I am trying to list and sort all running processes in Windows by their memory consumption with the python psutil module. However when I query a processes `memory_info` attribute none of the various metrics will get above 4 gigabytes. Why  is this limited and how can I get around this?

I did try using `proc.memory_full_info()` which would theoretically fix this issue with the `uss` memory metric, however I cannot figure out how to do this without causing an AccessDenied error.

sample script:

```
import psutil
from psutil._common import bytes2human

procs = [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['memory_info', 'memory_percent', 'name'])]

for proc in sorted(procs, key=lambda p: p['memory_percent'], reverse=True):
    print("{} - {}".format(proc['name'], bytes2human(getattr(proc['memory_info'], 'rss'))))
```

I'm open to any other way of profiling memory usage, psutil just seems to be the best tool I found out there.

Comment: The question is: should it return something above *4GiB*? Also what does `sys.maxsize` return / print?

Comment: Yes, it definitely should.. Sorry I didn't include any specific data but I am currently running processes with 10G+ in taskmanager.exe and they still cap out at 4G. It terms of `sys.maxsize` do you think python just can't hold a number that big, if I understand you correctly? I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: To answer your question though, `sys.maxsize` returns `2147483647`. Instead of using the bytes2human function if I just return the actual byte size in psutil the maximum I currently get is `4294967295`.

Comment: It's what I imagined. You're running *32bit* *Python*. Now I didn't get into *psutils* internals (the *C* code), but I assume it uses *32bit* unsigned integral types - which can hold values up to *4GiB*). Try installing a *64bit* *Python* and run your code there.

Comment: Well that's frustrating, but seems like you're right. Not loving the idea of switching my python version at this point but if that's what I have to do... Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't have to switch any versions. Just install the *64bit* version (for example I have more than 30 *Python* instances on my laptop), and run the code with that one. It should work perfectly (except some rare cases when code is extremely poorly written).

Comment: And updating all modules. My workstation isn't online so that is a manual process... I'm just surprised that psutil didn't get around that issue, it's just a query so I would have thought it isn't an issue. Ah well.

Comment: Actually, I think it did for *64bit*. In general, *32bit* is now for backwards compatibility only. Also migrating the modules shouldn't be hard. `pip freeze` + `pip install -r`.

Comment: Yeah just finished and it's working great now, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! I also added an answer with more explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using *32bit* *Python*. By default a *32bit* process has a *4GiB* memory limit. On a software level, that limit comes from the underlying *C* types limits (and *psutil*'s core is written in *C*). 
For example, almost all [[MS.Docs]: PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-process_memory_counters) members have the *SIZE_T* type.

Example:

- *32bit*:

  > ```
  > >>> import sys, ctypes
  > >>> from ctypes import wintypes
  > >>> sys.version
  > '3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]'
  > >>>
  > >>> ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.DWORD), ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_size_t), ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.HANDLE)
  > (4, 4, 4)
  > ```
- *64bit*:

  > ```
  > >>> import sys, ctypes
  > >>> from ctypes import wintypes
  > >>> sys.version
  > '3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'
  > >>>
  > >>> ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.DWORD), ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_size_t), ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.HANDLE)
  > (4, 8, 8)
  > ```

For more details on how to distinguish between different *CPU* architectures *Python* processes, check: [[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os/50053286#50053286)