# Why does it continue to say that the whl file is not supported on this platform?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm attempting to set up pygame on another computer, but it continues to say that my wheel is not supported.
I've downloaded and upgraded my wheel and the pip install function, and I also am running python 3.7.4, please help me.
This is what it says:

> ERROR: pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: it does not say that the file type is not spported

Comment: What platform are you installing on?

Comment: I'm installing on windows 10.

Comment: 32bit or 64bit windows?

Comment: Its 64bit windows

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are  using a 32 bit Python on a 64 bit Windows.

[determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os)

Installing the following file solved the issue:  install this package

```
pip install pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```