# How to install TensorFlow on Python 3.7

Tags: visual-studio-code, python, python-3.x, tensorflow

How to install TensorFlow on Python 3.7

Trying:

```
D:\Users\Downloads>pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Windows 10 OS

And with vent error, too

```
(venv) C:\Users\KvaksManYT>pip install --upgrade tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: you need to add your OS version.  also add python error traceback

Comment: @MrSCoder I added my OS version and type

Comment: read the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a virtual environment using `pip install vitualenv`. Then, depending on your OS, you want to create and activate an environment.

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Then, activate this environment using,

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Now, you can install any Python packages you want.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

Comment: C:\Users\KvaksManYT>pip install vitualenv
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vitualenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vitualenv

Comment: I've encountered this error in Windows before. The best solution to this is to use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section). It is easy to install, and version conflicts etc. are rare.

Comment: Pls write about anaconda as answer(lib is installing; I need to run Python progs from console or I can from IDLE?)

Comment: You can run Python programs from the console easily and use [Anaconda](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) with it. I would suggest using an IDE instead of IDLE like Pycharm and setting the environment to your Anaconda environment[] (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/). Many Python packages are a pain to set up on Windows directly and this is the best way everything works.

Answer (score 2):

you can install Tensorflow follow those steps
Ubuntu/Linux /mac os /windows

virtualenv does not require a mention pip version

for system install, you need to mention pip version

**upgrade pip version**

pip install --upgrade pip

```
#virtualenv install

pip install --upgrade tensorflow

#system install
pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow
```

reference https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: On my PC installed pip 20.0.2 - the latest

Comment: using this command
pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow  #  TensorFlow installed in system python environments install in $HOME

my answer work for you please mark as correct answer.

Comment: (venv) C:\Users\KvaksManYT>pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow\n
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)\n
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow\n

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with **Windows 10 x64**, and it was caused because I was using the **wrong Python version**, both globally and in the `venv`. I found questions on the issue multiple times on the internet, including yours.

### Be sure to use Python versions 3.5-3.8, as per [requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install), **but also x64, not x32**.

Namely, I ran into this error using both

- a `venv` with `3.9.1 x64` (`python --version`),
- and my globally installed `3.8.2 x32` (`python3 --version`).

So, I downloaded the [x64-version of Python 3.8.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) from here.

### Note that the **command `venv` does not allow specifying the python version used in the virtual environment**,

as per [an answer on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) So I used `virtualenv`, which I obviously had to install in my **global** Python version first.

To specify the Python version used in the `venv`, I used the command `virtualenv`, as in:

```
virtualenv --python="C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe myvenv
```

where you have to give the path to the newly downloaded Python distribution you want to use, if there are several on your PC (for example, I had `Python38-32` and `Python39` folders in that directory).

### Check Python versions in virtual environment

After I activate my `myvenv`, created as above, I verify the Python versions as follows:

```
python3 --version
> Python 3.8.2
python --version
> Python 3.8.6
```

Then, using the command

```
import struct
print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)
```

Within either `python3` or `python`, shows me whether the version is 32bit or 64bit, [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit). The `python` returns a `64`, so that is the one you want to use (not `python3`).

Finally, within the virtual environment, you can run

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and it will download and install. (Meanwhile, `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` would still return your error inside and outside the virtual enviroment.)