# How to install a win32 version of python using win64 anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, anaconda3

I am trying to set up the [covarep](https://covarep.github.io/covarep/) software on my win64 machine for a project and need to install 'a Windows 32-bit version of Python 2.7, 3.3, and/or 3.4'.

I used conda (platform win-64) to run `conda create -n "covarep-env" python=3.4.0 -c free`

This created an environment that has python version 3.4.0, but this obviously defaults to installing the win-64 version.

After following the covarep README instructions and running `import covarep_py` in python, I get the error

```
RuntimeError: To call deployed MATLAB code on a win32 machine, you must run a win32 version of Python. Details: C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v90\runtime\win32
```

Q: Is there a way to specify the win32 platform version of python when running `conda create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the ***CONDA_FORCE_32BIT*** environment variable (got it from [[YouTube]: DotPi - Create 32-bit Python Environments from a 64-bit Conda Installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1Zzw-Y_n2g)) before creating the environment (not related to (previous) *"**environment** variable"*).

Unfortunately the only **official** reference I could find is [[Anaconda.Docs]: Troubleshooting - Using 32- and 64-bit libraries and CONDA_FORCE_32BIT](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#using-32-and-64-bit-libraries-and-conda-force-32bit).

Example (*Anaconda Prompt* - I used *Python 3.6* as an example, as I need it for another task):

> ```
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> :: Create a "regular" (pc064) environment
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> conda create -n py_pc064_03_06_02 python=3.6.2
> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: done
>
>
> ==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
>   current version: 4.14.0
>   latest version: 22.9.0
>
> Please update conda by running
>
>     $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
>
>
>
> ## Package Plan ##
>
>   environment location: f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_06_02
>
>   added / updated specs:
>     - python=3.6.2
>
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
>   certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2021.5.30-py36haa95532_0
>   pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-21.2.2-py36haa95532_0
>   python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.6.2-h09676a0_15
>   setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-58.0.4-py36haa95532_0
>   vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
>   vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
>   wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.37.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
>   wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0
>
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Preparing transaction: done
> Verifying transaction: done
> Executing transaction: done
> #
> # To activate this environment, use
> #
> #     $ conda activate py_pc064_03_06_02
> #
> # To deactivate an active environment, use
> #
> #     $ conda deactivate
>
> Retrieving notices: ...working... done
>
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]>
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> :: SET ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
>
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> :: Create a funky (pc032) environment
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> conda create -n py_pc032_03_06_02 python=3.6.2
> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: done
>
> ## Package Plan ##
>
>   environment location: f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc032_03_06_02
>
>   added / updated specs:
>     - python=3.6.2
>
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
>     package                    |            build
>     ---------------------------|-----------------
>     certifi-2021.5.30          |   py36h9f7ea03_0         140 KB
>     pip-21.2.2                 |   py36h9f7ea03_0         1.8 MB
>     python-3.6.2               |      hb0ff576_15        12.8 MB
>     setuptools-58.0.4          |   py36h9f7ea03_0         777 KB
>     vc-14.2                    |       h21ff451_1           8 KB
>     vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016 |       h5e58377_2        1000 KB
>     wheel-0.37.1               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          33 KB
>     wincertstore-0.2           |   py36hcdd9a18_0          14 KB
>     ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                            Total:        16.5 MB
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
>   certifi            pkgs/main/win-32::certifi-2021.5.30-py36h9f7ea03_0
>   pip                pkgs/main/win-32::pip-21.2.2-py36h9f7ea03_0
>   python             pkgs/main/win-32::python-3.6.2-hb0ff576_15
>   setuptools         pkgs/main/win-32::setuptools-58.0.4-py36h9f7ea03_0
>   vc                 pkgs/main/win-32::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
>   vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-32::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
>   wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.37.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
>   wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-32::wincertstore-0.2-py36hcdd9a18_0
>
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages
> vc-14.2              | 8 KB      | ############################################################################ | 100%
> vs2015_runtime-14.27 | 1000 KB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
> certifi-2021.5.30    | 140 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
> setuptools-58.0.4    | 777 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
> wincertstore-0.2     | 14 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
> pip-21.2.2           | 1.8 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
> python-3.6.2         | 12.8 MB   | ############################################################################ | 100%
> wheel-0.37.1         | 33 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
> Preparing transaction: done
> Verifying transaction: done
> Executing transaction: done
> #
> # To activate this environment, use
> #
> #     $ conda activate py_pc032_03_06_02
> #
> # To deactivate an active environment, use
> #
> #     $ conda deactivate
>
> Retrieving notices: ...working... done
>
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> :: RESET ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE (to avoid any future problems in this terminal)
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=
>
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> conda env list
> # conda environments:
> #
>                          F:\Install\pc032\Intel\OneAPI\Version\intelpython\python3.7
>                          F:\Install\pc032\Intel\OneAPI\Version\intelpython\python3.7\envs\2021.1.1
> base                  *  f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version
> py_pc032_03_06_02        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc032_03_06_02
> py_pc064_03_06_02        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_06_02
> py_pc064_03_08_08        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_08_08
> py_pc064_03_10_00        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_10_00
> ```

Verify the created environments (check [[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053286/4788546) for more details):

> ```
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> :: Activate pc064 env
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> conda activate py_pc064_03_06_02
>
> (py_pc064_03_06_02) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> python
> Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 30 2017, 11:52:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import ctypes as cts
> >>> print(cts.sizeof(cts.c_void_p) * 8)
> 64
> >>> ^Z
>
>
> (py_pc064_03_06_02) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> conda deactivate
>
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> :: Activate pc032 env
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> conda activate py_pc032_03_06_02
>
> (py_pc032_03_06_02) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> python
> Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 30 2017, 11:44:55) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import ctypes as cts
> >>> print(cts.sizeof(cts.c_void_p) * 8)
> 32
> >>> ^Z
>
>
> (py_pc032_03_06_02) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]> conda deactivate
>
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:C:\Users\cfati]>
> ```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you! Video was also super helpful