Python winreg is updating SOMETHING, but not the Windows registry
I am using winreg to read, write, and change the Windows registry. My program flips a lot of different settings to fix things that annoy me about the windows defaults. When I run it, it seems to work. The changes even persist between Flask runs, even after restarting Windows Explorer, and the computer.
But every time I check the registry, the changes aren’t there. I already verified that everything is 64bit. I am running VScode as admin (and running flask through the terminal there). Just in case, I ran it in an admin terminal outside of vscode too.
No matter what I try, it tells me it’s changing the registry when it actually isn’t. It’s completely punking me. I've tried reopening Windows Explorer, closing and reopening the Registry, and restarting the system. None made a difference.
For the settings where I created a value and set it's "data" attribute, that persists between sessions and I can test for it in my code as if it's storing it SOMEWHERE.
This is the code:
NOTE: if you're at all worried about the registry changes below, back up your registry before running this
import winreg

def hive_name(hive):
    if hive == winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
        return "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"
    elif hive == winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
        return "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
    elif hive == winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT:
        return "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"
    elif hive == winreg.HKEY_USERS:
        return "HKEY_USERS"
    elif hive == winreg.HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA:
        return "HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA"
    elif hive == winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG:
        return "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG"
    else:
        return "UNKNOWN_HIVE"

def open_or_create_key(hive, path):
    try:
        # Open the registry key for reading and writing in 64-bit view
        key = winreg.OpenKey(hive, path, 0, winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WRITE | winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
        print(f"Key opened: {hive_name(hive)}\\{path}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Handle if the key doesn't exist
        print(f"Creating key: {hive_name(hive)}\\{path}")
        key = winreg.CreateKeyEx(hive, path, 0, winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WRITE | winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
    except PermissionError:
        # Handle if there are permission issues
        print(f"Permission denied while accessing the key: {hive_name(hive)}\\{path}")
        key = None
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any other exceptions
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        key = None
    return key

def get_value(key,which):
    try:
        value, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, which)
        print(f"Current value: {value}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Current value: <not set>")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while querying the value: {e}")

def set_value(key,which,what):
    try:
        winreg.SetValueEx(key, which, 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, what)
        print (which, "was set to", what)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print (which, "could not be set to", what)

def close_key(key):
    if key:
        winreg.CloseKey(key)
        print("Key closed.")

# Test the open_or_create_key function
if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("# This key does exist on my system and has tons of values")
    print("# Expected Output: Key opened: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced")
    key = open_or_create_key(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced")
    print("# Value name DisallowShaking is NOT in my registry.")
    print("# Expected Output: Current value: <not set> ")
    # Prevents the windows "feature" of minimizing everything if you "shake" a window while dragging. Does nothing if the value isn't actually set.
    get_value(key,"DisallowShaking")
    print("# Value name HideFileExt IS in my registry.")
    print("# Expected Output: HideFileExt set to X (where X is the value set in the code) - needs to be checked in the registry to see if it changed between runs")
    # enables or disables hiding of file extensions. 0 to not hide it.
    set_value(key,"HideFileExt",1)
    close_key(key)

    # This restores the Windows 10 right-click context menu to your system in Windows 11 if the key is present. It has no effect when left
    print("# Neither {86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2} nor InprocServer32 exist in my registry.")
    print("# Expected Output: Creating Key: Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32")
    key = open_or_create_key(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32")
    close_key(key)

    # Setting this key and vlue restores the Windows 10 Windows Explorer ribbon. 
    print("# The Blocked key does not exist in my registry.")
    print("# Expected Output: Creating Key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked")
    key = open_or_create_key(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked")
    print("# If the key were created, then I can test for value {e2bf9676-5f8f-435c-97eb-11607a5bedf7} which should not exist yet.")
    print("# Expected Output: An error occurred while querying the value:  ")
    get_value(key,"{e2bf9676-5f8f-435c-97eb-11607a5bedf7}")
    set_value(key,"{e2bf9676-5f8f-435c-97eb-11607a5bedf7}", 1)
    close_key(key)


When I run the above (in VsCode terminal with VsCode run as admin), I get the following output:
# This key does exist on my system and has tons of values
# Expected Output: Key opened: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
Key opened: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
# Value name DisallowShaking is NOT in my registry.
# Expected Output: Current value: <not set>
Current value: 1
# Value name HideFileExt IS in my registry.
# Expected Output: HideFileExt set to X (where X is the value set in the code) - needs to be checked in the registry to see if it changed between runs
HideFileExt was set to 1
Key closed.
# Neither {86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2} nor InprocServer32 exist in my registry.
# Expected Output: Creating Key: Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32
Key opened: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32
Key closed.
# The Blocked key does not exist in my registry.
# Expected Output: Creating Key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked
Key opened: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked
# If the key were created, then I can test for value {e2bf9676-5f8f-435c-97eb-11607a5bedf7} which should not exist yet.
# Expected Output: An error occurred while querying the value:
Current value: <not set>
Key closed.

Despite that, the state of my registry after running the above is as follows:

DisallowShaking was NOT created

HideFileExt was NOT set to 1


key Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32 is NOT created


key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked is NOT created

value {e2bf9676-5f8f-435c-97eb-11607a5bedf7} is clearly does not exist, but outputs as if it were.



And somehow, the state is preserved. I added a "set_value" to the last value ({e2bf9676-5f8f-435c-97eb-11607a5bedf7}) on a subsequent run and the value I set persisted between runs of the program. The key and value both still don't exist in my registry.
The common responses are the 64 vs 32 bit issue which isn't in play (the system, python, and the Regedit are all 64 bit). I've checked the "VirtualStore" - I checked the ENTIRE registry for any text containing one of the values I set and it's not there (except when I run the code... then it thinks it is).

You're basing the assumption that the key isn't there on what? Also that assumption is false after running the script once.

Checking for the key with Regedit. I checked it with PowerShell for good measure. And it doesn't matter how many times I run the script, because it detects the key as being there when it isn't, it never reaches the "create" line.

Windows and Python are both 64 bit? Have you tried this with other registry keys, from the same hive and from another one?

Unless python downloads 32 bit by default, yes. Everything is 64 bit. As for other keys,  I'm working on a tool with a series of over 30 different registry keys that I change one at a time. Somehow the state is preserved when I toggle the changes between program loads so the data is being toggled SOMEWHERE.

I found a test string to check if it's 64bit and it is.

Windows itself does a lot of registry redirection, making it hard to verify where something is actually going.  Use a unique value that you can search for.

Several of the keys and values don't exist in the registry so they should be created. After the code runs, I checked the registry from its root looking for the values and they were not there. @MarkRansom

Run procmon to see what is happening.

Did you try hitting F5 in regedit to refresh the content?  It doesn't actively push changes made outside of the viewer.

@James, per my post " I've tried reopening Windows Explorer, closing and reopening the Registry, and restarting the system. None made a difference." I have also tried hitting f5 first before any of that too.

@Luke, how would I use procmon to discover anything in this case?

It would tell you if you're actually reading/writing what you think you're reading/writing.

Each user has its own HKCU so maybe you should try this? https://superuser.com/questions/46399/access-another-users-hkey-current-user-registry-branch

@x6dec3fb8, I have searched the entire registry for some of the keys and values and they are not there.

Perhaps vscode is doing something funky. Try running script from command line instead. I haven't tried in vscode as I don't use it, but the code works fine for me from command line (Windows 10).

@Luke, I did try running it from the terminal and it made no difference.

Well, I think your only option is to run procmon and see where registry data is being read from and written to.

have you tried to reinstall python? this could be a bug in winreg, what version are you running?

@GTK using 3.10.11. When I checked my system, I noticed I have 3.11.5150 as well and that one says (64bit) explicitly. I used a command previously to verify it was 64 bit, but I upgraded to 3.12 anyway and checked it too (per these instructions): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit. I rebuilt my venv, pip installed flask, and now it works! You found it! If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it. There's a bounty on this question that belongs to you.

I guess the good old reinstall did save the day once again, I will post it as an answer!

I think you need to reinstall python.

As per my comment, I assume it was most likely an issue with the older version of python/winreg, as always restarting/reinstalling seem to solve these types of cryptic problems.
Although there were changes between 3.10 and 3.12 to how winreg manages registry key handles, that should not have anything to do with it.
I still could not reproduce the problem with python 3.10.11 or 3.12.11, perhaps it's just a buggy/corrupt python install?

To be specific, per the comment above, I uninstalled python 3.10, installed 3.12 and rebuilt my venv and flask install using:
python -m venv venv
pip install flask

just to clarify, the version you were running the code on was 3.10 not 3.11? and you tried with both global/venv and did not work with either? since no one was able to reproduce the problem, it is very hard to pinpoint what was going on

I only tried with 3.10.  I was going to update to 3.11, but noticed 3.12 was out. So I installed 3.12, rebuilt my venv and flask then it worked.

I doubt flask/venv had anything to do with it, also I installed the exact version you used, and still could not reproduce the problem.

I have no idea. But reinstalling worked.

Yeah, I followed your step. everything is working well.
